# Iterate through array inside array

Tags: meteor

I want to create a quiz application. To sumarize answers, and decide which answer is correct, I have an item in the Collection like this:

```
{
"_id" : "Q5D63eQA8AnYHJrRc",
"userId" : "X67n8vbiraEsEvWYD",
"username" : "ania",
"test" : {
    "T1" : {
        "Q1" : "A",
        "Q2" : "D",
        "Q3" : "D"
    },
    "T2" : {
        "Q1" : "A",
        "Q2" : "D",
        "Q3" : "D"
    }
}}
```

I've also tried to use [ to indicate that it's an array.

Right now I use:

```
    <ul class="list-group nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        {{#each Answers}}
            {{>usernamesList}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>

</template>

<template name="usernamesList">
    <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item answer">{{username}}</a></li>
    {{test.T1.Q1}}
</template>
```

I'm able to get the value of Q1, but I can't display every answer in the loop by using another {{#each}}.
I've tried to create an array, but I also have to distinguish which answer belongs to which question and test.

EDIT:

Collection

```
Answers = new Mongo.Collection("answers");
```

Helper:

```
Template.admin.helpers({
    Questions: function() {
        return Questions.find({});
    },
    Answers: function() {
        return Answers.find({});
    }
});
```

I've also tried to create the collection like this:

```
{"userId" : "X67n8vbiraEsEvWYD",
"username" : "ania",
    "test" : [{
        "T1" :[{ 
         "Q1":"A",
         "Q2":"D",
         "Q3":"D"
    }],
        "T2" : [{
         "Q1":"A",
         "Q2":"D",
         "Q3":"D"
    }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your helper for `Answers`? Your document doesn't contain any arrays, so you need to build one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usernamesList template could have another #each for something that does return an array. You can use a helper to convert the various objects you want to loop through into arrays of objects with the properties you want to see.

I'm not 100% sure what you're going for here, but it seems like you want three loops:

```
Users
  ->  Tests
      ->  Answers
```

To do so, given the structure you specify above, you could do something like this:

```
<template name='main'>
  <ul class="list-group nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        {{#each Answers}}
            {{>usernamesList}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name='usernamesList'>  
  <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item answer">{{username}}</a></li>
    <ul><!-- get each test as a sub-bullet -->
      {{#each usersTests}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
        <ul><!-- get each question's answer as a sub-bullet -->
          {{#each testAnswers}}
            <li><strong>{{question}}</strong>: {{answer}}</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Then just reformat your data to be in arrays with the appropriate helpers:

```
Template.main.helpers({
  Answers: function() { return Answers.find(); } // assumes you are returning a cursor that looks exactly as your collection is defined above
    });

Template.usernamesList.helpers({
   usersTests: function() { // Convert the `test` object into an array of objects:
    var test = this.test;
    return _.map(Object.keys(test), function(key) { 
      var answers = _.map(Object.keys(test[key]), function(question) { // also go ahead and convert this to objects
        return {question: question, answer: test[key][question]};
      });

      return {name: key, testAnswers: answers}; // resulting array looks like [{test: 'T1', testAnswers: [{question: 'Q1', answer: 'A', ...}]}]
    });
  }
});
```

Once they are arrays you can iterate through them with `{{#each}}`.  Recognize that HTML within the `{{#each}}` block will get the object you're iterating over as the data context -- so for instance when we iterate over the result of `userTests`, the data context is now an object in the format:

```
{test: 'T1', 
  testAnswers: [{question: 'Q1', answer: 'A', ...}]
}
```

So `testAnswers` is directly accessible as an array.  We can then iterate over that array by calling `{{#each testAnswers}}`, and an object in the format

```
{question: 'Q1', answer: 'A'}
```

is now the data context, which means the `question` and `answer` keys are available.

Depending on your use case and what you may be doing with those objects in the Collection, I might recommend storing them as arrays within the collection itself so that you don't have to go through the mapping from object to array as done in the `usersTests` helper.